# I am getting timeout exception even after using try catch in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeoutexception

I am using selenium to find a page and perform some action.

I have coded it in a way that if chrome is not able to find the page, go to the next one.

I have used try-catch for it but it is failing sometimes.

```
driver.get(url.text())
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,'nav'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(element_present)

except:
    driver.close()
    continue
```

Sometimes it runs perfectly but sometimes it throws timeout exception...
IDK why? It should go to exception...

```
File "index.py", line 124, in requests
driver.get(url.text())
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
```

Any insights?

Comment: you are waiting for 50 seconds. You're saying that sometimes it reaches the 50 seconds and timeouts? when you open that page by hand, is it fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.get(url.text())` is not inside the `try except` block, so the exception won't be caught. The driver took too much time to load, so you received `TimeoutException` on the `get()` command. You can set it using

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in line

```
driver.get(url.text())
```

which is not in try-except. Include this line in the try-except block.